# How to make static struct, with calling fork()

Tags: c, struct, fork

I have a problem with struct

This is a brief from the code:

```
struct registration{
    long port;           // port number
    char host_name[MAXSIZE]; // host name of the client
};

struct registration regDB[MAXUSER]; //  

void handelClient(struct packet *pkt){
    int k;
    for(k=0;k<MAXUSER;k++){
        printf("\nIndex:%i H:%s  P:%ld",k,regDB[k].host_name,regDB[k].port);
    }
}// handelC...

int main( int argc , char *argv[]){ 
    int pid;
    while(1){   
        if((clientSock=accept(serverSock,(struct sockaddr *)&clientInfo,&sockLength))==-1){
            perror("\nError Accept: ");
        }// if
        pid=fork();
        if(pid<0){
            perror("\nError Fork");
        }
        if(pid==0){
            handleClient(clientSock);
        }
    }// while
    return 0;
}//main
```

the problem is that each call for handleClient() is creating a new struct of **regDB**

```
struct registration regDB[MAXUSER]
```

So, when I print the contains of **regDB** in each call of **handleClient()** is different. 
I want to make  **regDB**  static in the whole program 
I tried to do this:

```
static struct registration regDB[MAXUSER];
```

but, it didn't work, still each call creating it's own struct.

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't work this way. Memory overwritten in a forked process does not have an effect on the original process. The solution is to use some sort of shared memory.

Comment: and how to do that ?!

Comment: Lookup “shared memory” and follow the first tutorial you find. Basically, you need to allocate a block of shared memory before forking. This block is going to be shared between the parent and its children, meaning changes done in the children propagate back to the parents.

Comment: Or... Use multi-threading. Threads (differently from forked processes) share memory segments (excluding stack).